# Convert a select into hours, minutes, and second in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, time, datediff

Given:

```
INSERT INTO EP_ACCESS (START_TIMESTAMP, DISCONNECT_TIMESTAMP)
VALUES (TO_DATE('2020-01-01 00:00:01','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE('2020-01-01 00:01:00','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

And:

```
SELECT SUM(E.Start_timestamp-E.Disconnect_timestamp) AS WATCHING_TIME
FROM EP_ACCESS
```

How can I convert the selected into hours, minutes, and seconds?

Comment: This will depend on the datatypes of START_TIMESTAMP and DISCONNECT_TIMESTAMP. Are they dates or timestamps?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - In the sample data provided, they are `date` data type (even though the column names include "timestamp"). Of course, it is entirely possible that the OP's real-life data uses a different data type...

Answer (score 5):

The difference of two dates in Oracle is a (possibly fractional) **number**, measured in days. If you need to convert this to hours, minutes and seconds, the best data type for the result is **interval day to second** and you can get that by multiplying your number (your sum, in your query) by `interval '1' day`. The result will be in days, hours, minutes and seconds.

As an aside, are you sure you are subtracting the right way? It seems to me that you should subtract the start timestamp from the disconnect timestamp - but you know your problem better than I do.

Here is an illustration using your "timestamps" (really, dates in Oracle), but with the difference going the right way.

```
select sum(disconnect_timestamp - start_timestamp) * interval '1' day as diff
from   ep_access
;

DIFF               
-------------------
+00 00:00:59.000000
```

The result shows 00 days, 00 hours, 00 minutes, 59.000000 seconds.